# Run simple Rest Java hello world program

Tags: java, spring, rest, maven, spring-boot

I am trying to run a simple Rest HelloWorld program as described in https://spring.io/guides/gs/rest-service/. I have downloaded Spring and Maven and added the `MAVEN_HOME` and `M3_HOME` environment variables. I have run the `mvn -v` command successfully in Windows command prompt. I browsed to the initial directory where the `pom.xml` is located. Then I run `mvn spring-root:run` but I get the following error:

> No plugin found for prefix 'spring-boot' in the current project and in the plugin groups [org.apache.maven.plugins, org.codehaus.mojo] available from the repositories [local (C:\Users\user.m2\repository), central (https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2)] -> [Help 1]

I have already searched for this error message on the internet but the suggestions are not solving my problem. Am I forgetting something related to any installation? Any idea or suggestion is highly appreciated.

Comment: You have to run `mvnw`, not `mvn` only. Or do `mvn clean install` and `java -jar target\...jar` ;-)

Comment: Thank you for your fast answer! If I run mvnw I get:
'mvnw' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
If I look in my Maven bin folder, I also do not see any file with this name. A mvn file I do see.. Where is the mvnw file located in the Maven directory?

Comment: When you download zip (from tutorial page) or when you create your spring-boot project using [Spring initializr](https://start.spring.io/) mvw s in archive. Did you try also other option I wrote - `mvn clean install` + `java -jar ...`?

Comment: Thanks you were right, the file is not in Maven directory but in downloaded tutorial. I was able to run mvnw now and I get the following error:
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-mavenplugin:1.5.10.RELEASE:run : Unable to find a suitable main class, please add a 'mainClass' property -> [Help 1]

When I run mvn clean install I get:
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-maven-plugin:1.5.10.RELEASE: Execution default of goal org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-maven-plugin:repackage failed: Unable to find main class -> [Help 1]

Comment: @OhadR  thanks, mvn spring-boot:run gives me following error message as well: [ERROR] No plugin found for prefix 'spring-root' in the current project and in the plugin groups [org.apache.maven.plugins, org.codehaus.mojo] available from the repositories [local (C:\Users\user\.m2\repository), spring-releases (https://repo.spring.io/libs-release), central (https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2)] -> [Help 1]

Comment: Are you logged as `user` to your machine? What is the content of your `c:\Users\user\.m2\repository\org\springframework\boot\spring-boot-maven-plugin\`` ? Is there such a folder ? There should be `1.5.10.RELEASE` with `spring-boot-maven-plugin-1.5.10.RELEASE.jar` (and other files in it). Are you behind proxy? Paste whole log from `mvn clean install`.

Comment: Yes there is 1.5.10.RELEASE dir with jar and other files. The complete error message is: [ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-maven-plugin:1.5.10.RELEASE:repackage (default) on project gs-rest-service: Execution default of goal org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-maven-plugin:1.5.10.RELEASE:repackage failed: Unable to find main class -> [Help 1]

Answer (score 0):

Oh, I realized now I had same issue in the past...

To address

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-maven-plugin:1.5.9.RELEASE:repackage (default) on project gs-rest-service: Execution default of goal org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-maven-plugin:1.5.9.RELEASE:repackage failed: Unable to find main class -> [Help 1]
```

You have to create `Application` class (something annotated with `@SpringBootApplication`)

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class Application {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
    }
}
```

or skip tests `mvn clean install -DskipTests`.

For `mvnw spring-boot:run` I'm getting ConnectException right now...

```
Downloading https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/apache/maven/apache-maven/3.3.9/apache-maven-3.3.9-bin.zip

Exception in thread "main" java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: connect
```

but it is very likely issue on my side...

Comment: Thanks for your help. I do not know why it doesn't work, I tried Gradle and that is working fine..